# How do I make my home IIS server accessible from the web?

Tags: iis, webserver, router, ip-address

I just visited: http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and found my IP Address. Now when I type my IP address in browser I see my router instead of my IIS which is OK because I am behind home router. But I'd like to see my IIS when I type my IP address instead of my gateway.

How do I change it so I can see my IIS instead of router page?

Comment: This is off topic for SF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit that page, they give you your *public* IP (which actually belongs to the WAN interface of your router) because that is all they are able to see due to your router's NAT functionality.

To get the actual private IP of your workstation, drop to a command prompt and type 'ipconfig'.

Comment: I know it is because of router's NAT functionality and I am not talking about my private IP. Put simply: *"I just need to access my IIS from web."*. How can I do that?

Comment: Well in your question, you sure didn't let on to that fact. To allow traffic to IIS from the web, you'll need to set up a port forward. Keep in mind, though that after doing this, you'll still need to use the private IP internally, as it's highly unlikely that your router supports hairpin NAT.

Comment: Didn't I say: *which is OK because I am behind home router*. Anyways, thanks. I will try to do a port forward.

Comment: One additional point. This may not work due to your ISP blocking ports. You're at home, on a residential connection.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your web server behind your router from outside, you need to have a look at port forwarding in the configuration of your router. You can forward trafic for an external port to port 80 or 443 of the machine where IIS is running so that you can access your web server from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup Port 80 forwarding for your web server in your router. 
by doing this all your outbound traffic will come to your system.